# Managing two relationships between 2 entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have two entities: UserProfile and Inbox

This is my code for `UserProfile`:

```
public partial class UserProfile {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    //--------------------------
    public virtual ICollection<Messages.Inbox> Inboxes { get; set; }
}

public partial class UserProfile {
    public static void Configure(DbModelBuilder mb) {
        mb.Entity<UserProfile>().HasKey(up => up.Id);
    }
}
```

And this is my code for `Inbox`:

```
public partial class Inbox {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }//FK to userProfile
    public Accounts.UserProfile User { get; set; }
    public DateTime MessageDateTime { get; set; }
    public string Context { get; set; }
    public int SenderId { get; set; }//FK to userProfile
    public Accounts.UserProfile Sender { get; set; }
}

public partial class Inbox {
    public static void Configure(DbModelBuilder mb) {
        mb.Entity<Inbox>().HasKey(up => up.Id);
        mb.Entity<Accounts.UserProfile>().HasMany(up => up.Inboxes)
            .WithRequired(p => p.User)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);
        mb.Entity<Accounts.UserProfile>().HasMany(up => up.Inboxes)
            .WithRequired(p => p.Sender)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.SenderId);
    }
}
```

How can I manage these two relations between `Inbox` and `UserProfile`?

Comment: I am not quiet sure what do you mean by "managing" here, but looking to your mapping, using EF when you add a new inbox entity for example you need to set the user/sender properties too, and once you set the parent inbox's objectState to be "Added", EF will mark the navigation properties to be added too, and that will add the 3 entities to the database, 1 Inbox and 2 UserProfiles. is this scenario valid for your business ?

Comment: @omar.alani , no , userId and senderId are just FK to UserProfile , eg we have a userProfile with Id '5' and an other with Id '8', and in inbox userid is 5 and senderid is 8

Comment: yep, so technically you can only set the SenderId/UserId and inbox can be saved correctly, but my previous scenario is still technically valid, which means you still can add users from the inbox entity, and if you don't want that to happen as you may setup the users separately, never expose the Sender/User properties through your service.

Comment: @Omar.Alani  i think got what you mean,  remove sender from inbox and use user in inbox, and in fluent-api : withrequired(p =>p.user ) for each hasForiegnKey (sender) and (user). Correct?

Comment: If you have a DTO that you expose to the user/ui to add inbox, that dto should not include User/Sender properties, just the Ids SenderId/UserId, but keep them in the Inbox entity, as you need to load some details about the User/Sender from the inbox entity, so instead of joining with UserProfile table, you can include the it using Entity-framework. hope that helps.

Comment: @Omar.Alani You should write your comments as an answer so they're useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DTO that you expose to the user/ui to add inbox, that dto should not include User/Sender properties, just the Ids SenderId/UserId, but keep them in the Inbox entity, as you need to load some details about the User/Sender from the inbox entity, so instead of joining with UserProfile table, you can include the it using Entity-framework. hope that helps.